# PHP - Append New Value to Form Data for Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some FormData that are going to be sent into another PHP file using Ajax Post.

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("form-id");
var form_data = new FormData(formElement);

var csrf_arr = csrf.split("=");
form_data.append(csrf_arr[0],csrf_arr[1]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your-url",
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        location.reload();
    }
})
```

What I'm trying to do here is to append a new single data inside the **form_data**

From my assumption, I could make it just by doing this

```
form_data.append("key","value");
```

But it is not sent through the ajax post or even not appended to the form_data as part of the FormData.

Am I making any mistake here or even there is certain rule for that?
Please give any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure csrf_arr actually has any values?

Comment: Yes, it just for security when you passing the data (Cross-Site Request Forgery).

Comment: Are you sure there arent `?` and `&` in your querystring. You try to split it by using `=` and then append it to the formdata object.

Comment: Yes @Mouser
Is it my current problem?

Comment: Can you see the values in your server side file?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and use the javascript debugger to see whats actually happening. Set a breakpoint on the first line of your code and then do whatever causes this script to run

Comment: @Mouser - Actually I have set the value of the csrf variable in another file like this
var csrf = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() . '=' . $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>";
That's why I could split it just like that.
But when I print it to the screen, the value is not appear actually.
I don't really get how it actually works, only to ensure you get the right passed data.

Comment: So the actual problem is that `csrf_arr` is empty?

Comment: Check your HTML to see what the actual value of csrf is.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response everyone. :(
@Mouser - Yes, actually I can't see it also after sent to the other file

Comment: @ralh - Here is the actual value of csrf
var csrf = "your_csrf_token_name=bb6ff34c26ff938822dd339c1682bbcc";

Answer (score 0):

Dear all of my friend,

I'm sorry. Actually it is just a mistake from myself.

I have fix this myself and found the mistake right inside my code.

**-- The javascript code --**

```
$( '#submitYours' ).on('click', function(){

    var formElement = document.getElementById("form-id");

    // Value of formElement consist of pair of data like:
    // qst_additional_name_for_the_key=value_of_the_key

    var form_data = new FormData(formElement);

    form_data.append('break','break');

    // to prevent confusion, i'm putting the csrf variable value here
    // but i'm not using this as printed variable later, just for security check
    var csrf = "your_csrf_token_name=bb6ff34c26ff938822dd339c1682bbcc";

    var csrf_arr = csrf.split("=");

    var x = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < elementId.length; x++){
        form_data.append(elementId[x], elementVal[x]);  

        // Appended data above is just an additional data from some array of data
        // and the format is the same with formElement
        // qst_additional_name_for_the_key=value_of_the_key
    }

    form_data.append("master_id",master_id);
    form_data.append(csrf_arr[0],csrf_arr[1]);

    addLoader("overlay-loader");
    runInAnimate("overlay-loader", "bounceInUp");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            runOutAnimate("overlay-loader", "overlay-loader", "bounceOutDown");
            location.reload();
        }
    })
});
```

**-- The url.php code --**

```
$temp = '';
$arr_in = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(!@$value) continue;

    if(substr($key, 0, 4) == 'qst_'){  // This is the real problem. 
                                       // The only data taken from the form_data
                                       // are the data containing string "qst_" in it
        if(is_array(@$value)){
            foreach(@$value as $val){
                $this->yourmodel->saveAnswer(substr($key, 4), strtolower(trim(@$val)));
                $temp = @$_POST[$key];
                $arr_in .= @$temp;
            }
        }else{
             $this->yourmodel->saveAnswer(substr($key, 4), strtolower(trim(@$value)));
             $temp = @$_POST[$key];
             $arr_in .= @$temp;
        }
    }else if($key == 'break'){    // remember my additional data? The string "break"
                                  // i just have to chek it here and put into my $arr_in variable,
                                  // so that I can use it now, because the previous conditional allow
                                  // only data containing string "qst_"
         $temp = @$_POST[$key];
         $arr_in .= @$temp;
    }
}

print json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => @$arr_in));
```

The conclusion is, nothing wrong if we just append the form_data manually

```
form_data.append('your_key','your_value');
```

Everything just the matter of how you access the data after it sent to another file.
My Mistake, everyone!
I'm sorry and thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: I'm glad that you found it out by yourself. A learning experience. The next time your post something on SO be sure to include all the relevant coding. We could've helped you more precisely if we had the relevant coding.

Comment: @Mouser - Yes my friend. Thanks for the advice. :)